# Check NetworkManager is DHCP or Static with command line Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dhcp, static-ip-address, networkmanager

How can I check the GUI network setting is set DHCP or Static with command line? for the active and connected interface in Ubuntu 18.04

I want one line command like grep give me static/dhcp or true/false

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can use `ip` command to check interface you're interested in.

E.g. to check the interface `eth0`:

```
if ip -6 addr show eth0  | grep -q dynamic; then
    echo "Uses DHCP addressing"
else
    echo "Uses static addressing"
fi
```

`-6` option is for checking IPv6 interface. You can use `-4` for IPv4.

Answer (score -1):

nmcli -f ipv4.method con show

If the output is auto, then it is DHCP.
If the output is manual, then it is static.

or

cat /etc/network/interfaces

`DHCP enabled`

auto eth0

iface eth0 inet dhcp

Comment: `nmcli -f ipv4.method con show` show error, in 18.04 `/etc/network/interfaces` replace with netplan

Comment: `nmcli -f ipv4.method con show` doesn't work.

Comment: Use `nmcli con show` to list connections, then `nmcli con show <connection_uuid> | grep ipv4.method` works for me.